# In Mac Excel 2011, how to format cell as percentage or currency based on content of another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

As far as I can tell, the Conditional Formatting feature doesn't support percentages. You can format styles (color, font, etc.), but not the actual content presentation itself.

I have two columns, one that labels the type of data that is in the second column, and then the data itself. For instance:

```
A           B
bids        0.0012
spreader    on
potency     0.75
```

I would like to format the data in column B, based on the content of column A. So for instance B1 should be currency, B2 should be text ("General" would be fine), and B3 should be Percentage.

Since I don't believe I can use regular conditional formatting, what are my options here? And if I'm wrong in my premise, please point me at how to accomplish what I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 does support custom formats like percentages with conditional formatting, but Excel 2011 Mac does not. You can however make the workbook in Excel 2013 and the Mac will interpret the rules correctly!

But if you don't have access to that, construct a nested IF formula and use string concatenation and the TEXT() function to specify the number formats.

Comment: Aha... not the first time that I've encountered features that the Mac version has not been given.  Bummer.  So how would I go about doing what you describe, since using a formula would destroy the data in column B?  I don't need to determine what the current formatting is, since the format is determined solely by the text in column A.  I still can't think of any way to get column B to format the cell based on the value in column A.  Suggestions?

Comment: Add the formulas to column C, referencing column B, and hide column B. Another trick I like using is coloring the font white so it looks hidden, but just remember that it's there so you don't overwrite it :)

Comment: I'm still not following.  I manually add rows in column B many times every day, so that column can't be hidden, and I still don't see how I can format that column conditionally as either currency, general, or percentage depending on the content in column A.  Adding another column that displays the value of column B depending on the text in column A, is no help because I have to input the values in column B anyway so...  Or am I completely misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: OK, keeping adding your data to B, but add this formula to C1 and copy down:
`=IF(A1="bids",TEXT(B1,"$0.0000"),IF(A1="spreader",TEXT(B1,"@"),TEXT(B1,"0.00%")))`

Comment: Yeah but that's exactly what I don't want... a second column with the exact same duplicated information in it, just presented in the correct format.  I want to conditionally format the cell I'm entering data into.

Comment: Since Excel 2011 doesn't support that, you got to give some where. Try grouping column B so it's easy to hide/unhide it so at least you don't see the data twice.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to find an alternative solution, but really if I have to keep hiding/unhiding all the time, I just won't bother.  I need a solution that will allow me to format the actual cells I am inputting the data into.

Comment: Then you'd need a macro, but you'd probably need a button to activate it, which is the same amount of work (one click) as having the column grouped.

Comment: Hmmm... hadn't thought about using a macro solution.  Could just hit the button periodically when I want to "clean up" my values, but it would have to iterate through the entire sheet every time, and it's rather long.  Might give it a try if I can't come up with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately the answer is that this is not possible with Mac Excel 2011, but is possible in Windows using the standard Conditional Formatting features.